# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.ValueTuple`2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tuples, asp.net-core-2.1

I've defined model in `_ShowComments.cshtml` view as a tuple type but when I want to call this Partialview

I get this error, when I call that method in `Default.cshtml`.

How can I solve it?

**Error Message:**

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'System.ValueTuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Models.Comment],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]',
>   but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'System.ValueTuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Models.Comment],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]'.

**Default.cshtml:**

```
@model List<Comment>

<div class="media mb-4">
    <div class="media-body">
        @Html.Partial("_ShowComments", ValueTuple.Create<List<Comment>, int?>(Model,null))
    </div>
</div>
```

**_ShowComments.cshtml:**

```
@model (IList<Comment> comments, int? parentId)

@if (Model.comments.Any(c => c.ParentId == Model.parentId))
{
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @foreach (var childComment in Model.comments.Where(c => c.ParentId == Model.parentId))
        {
            <li class="media">
                @Html.Partial("_ShowComments", (Model.comments, childComment.Id))
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a `ValueTuple<List<Comment>, int?>` when the view is expecting a `ValueTuple<IList<Comment>, int?>` (note the `List` vs `IList`) and the compiler sees these as different types. Use the correct tuple type:

```
@Html.Partial("_ShowComments", ValueTuple.Create<IList<Comment>, int?>(Model,null))
```

Or, in my opinion, the cleaner syntax:

```
@Html.Partial("_ShowComments", ((IList<Comment>)Model,null))
```

Or, my preferred solution, create a proper class to hold the values:

```
public class ShowCommentsModel
{
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And switch the view to use:

```
@model ShowCommentsModel
```